# how to connect ODBC connection in Pentaho Data Integration tool

Tags: oracle, pentaho-data-integration, jdbc-odbc

I'm using pentaho data integration tool. Currently we are using Native JDBC connection to connect respective DB. But if any changes in the respective port or hostname. Again I need to all the location in the PDI process.

Instead of this, how can I create common connection details. If any changes in the port or hostname in one location, it should take automatically the new one. (I think this is achieved by ODBC connectivity).

Any suggestion.
Thanks.

Common connection in pentaho data integration